# To find $g(x)$satisfying $ g(x+1)=g(x), \forall x \in R.$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a real-valued measurable function defined on $R$ and $f(x+1)=f(x),a.e.$ question: find out $g(x)$ such that $g(x)=f(x)$ a.e.  satisfying $ g(x+1)=g(x), \forall x \in R.$

i very appreciate that who can give me some hints.

Comment: do we have to find all such $g(x)$?

Comment: Show that for almost all $x$, $f(x+n)=f(x)$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$. Once you have this, redefine $f$ on the complement of this set (as $0$, say).

Comment: I think that you would basically show that the functional equation plus measurability implies $g(x)=0$. I don't think there are nontrivial examples, unless there is something pathological I'm not aware of.

Comment: thanks~~i've worked out it with your help.@Andrés Caicedo